# souphttpsrc receive http stream from vlc, connection refuse

Tags: stream, gstreamer, vlc, http-live-streaming, http-streaming

I'm trying to receive a video (non-audio) stream from VLC with HTTP protocol.
After I use VLC to stream video over HTTP, I use Gstreamer to receive streaming video, but I receive error from `"udpsrc: connection refuse"` (although I use `souphttpsrc`).

Here is my pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=http://192.168.1.104:65000/http ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! waylandsink sync=0 qos=0 max-lateness=-1
```

Please give me any idea you have!
Thank you so much!

Comment: Adding `GST_DEBUG=5` before the command might help. See http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html.